# create a view for multiple queries in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have 4 SQL queries that fetch data from the same table and I was wondering whether you can create a view containing multiple queries. For instance, one of these queries looks something like:

```
SELECT Count(COLUMN1) FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN3 > '01-Oct-12' AND COLUMN3< '01-Nov-12'
```

whereas another looks like:

```
SELECT Count(COLUMN2) FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN3 > '01-Oct-12' AND COLUMN3 < '01-Nov-12'
```

Thanks,

I.

Comment: What is the shape ofthe query's project - one column or four?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest implementation would be:

```
create or replace view v23 as 
     select count(column1) as col1_count
            , count(column2) as col2_count
     from TABLE1
      WHERE COLUMN3 > '01-Oct-12' AND COLUMN3 < '01-Nov-12'
```

But if not all your queries use the same criteria you could use scalar sub-queries:

```
create or replace view v23 as 
  select 
     (select count(column1) from TABLE1 
        WHERE COLUMN3 > '01-Oct-12' AND COLUMN3 < '01-Nov-12' ) as col1_count 
     , (select count(column2) from TABLE2 
        WHERE COLUMN3 > '01-Oct-12' AND COLUMN3 < '01-Nov-12' ) as col2_count
  from dual
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE VIEW viewname AS
SELECT Count(COLUMN1) as col1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN3 > '01-Oct-12' AND COLUMN3< '01-Nov-12'
union all
SELECT Count(COLUMN2) as col1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN3 > '01-Oct-12' AND COLUMN3 < '01-Nov-12'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the data in the same recordset and same column, then you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT Count(COLUMN1) As CNT, 'Q1' as Src
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE COLUMN3 > '01-Oct-12' 
 AND COLUMN3< '01-Nov-12'
UNION ALL
SELECT Count(COLUMN2) as Cnt, 'Q2' as Src
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE COLUMN3 > '01-Oct-12' 
  AND COLUMN3 < '01-Nov-12'
```

I included a column, to help you identify which query your data is coming from.  If that is unneeded then you can drop using it.